# Bearer Authentication in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, ecmascript-6, superagent

How can I use Bearer Authentication with superagent in React?
I am not sure in syntax and can't find an example.

What I do now

```js
   showTransactionList = () => {
        superagent
            .post('http://193.124.114.46:3001/api/protected/transactions')
            .set({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.id_token})
            .accept('application/json')
            .then(res => {
                const posts = JSON.stringify(res.body);
                console.log(posts);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;                    
            });
    }
```

Thnx!

Comment: When I ping your endpoint with no Auth header, I get `UnauthorizedError: No Authorization header was found`.  With a token of 'test', I get `UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed`.  With an actual jwt, I get `UnauthorizedError: invalid signature`. Are you able to determine whether the header is being set at all and which response you are getting?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Everything works not. And all ok with this code. Prooblem was in id_token (it was emplty) ,Sorry,  And sending SET not like a single object was useful too. Thnx A LOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way headers are set is by providing the header item name and value, try:

```
showTransactionList = () => {
    superagent
        .post('http://193.124.114.46:3001/api/protected/transactions')
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.state.id_token)
        .accept('application/json')
        .then(res => {
            const posts = JSON.stringify(res.body);
            console.log(posts);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;                    
        });
}
```

So instead of setting the object in the header, pass it as 2 parameters (name, value).

Comment: The same result.

Comment: Then probably you should use the (superagent-auth-bearer) plugin which is provided for this purpose https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-auth-bearer

Comment: sending SET not like a single object was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

rather than setting the full header with

`.set({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.id_token})`

you can use

`.auth(this.state.id_token, { type: 'bearer' })`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.auth('Bearer', this.state.id_token)`
http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#authentication

Comment: no. it doesn't help. response the same Error: "Unauthorized"

Comment: Are you able to see any Auth being added in the HTTP request in console or possibly any proxy?